# Use LogonUserW and execute Application with Handle

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to implement a C++ application for the first time, so be gentle :).

I installed CLion and set up MinGW.

First, I already fail on using the Windows API [`LogonUserW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw). My Application runs into a error which results in:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Please press Enter to continue... " << std::endl;
    getch();

    DWORD dwLogonType = LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK ;
    DWORD dwLogonProvider = LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 ;
    PHANDLE hToken = NULL ;

    BOOL result = ::LogonUserW(
            L"de313e",
            L"DOMAIN",
            L"PASSWORD",
            dwLogonType,
            dwLogonProvider,
            hToken);

    if (result)
        std::cout << "It worked" << std::endl ;
    else
        std::cout << "Not worked" << std::endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

My intention is to either:

- Login as an admin user and execute a process with the token

OR

- Execute an Application with Administrator privileges

I know that there is an API call named [`CreateProcessAsUserA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera), but with an API Monitor I can retrieve the password.

Therefore I would love to use [`LogonUserW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw) as the parameter for password:

> lpszPassword A pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the plaintext password for the user account specified by lpszUsername.

Which I wanted to do.

I hope someone can help me with that.

Comment: Change `PHANDLE hToken = NULL ;` to `HANDLE hToken;` and the last parameter of the call from `hToken` to `&hToken`.

Comment: CreateProcessAsUser is not less secure than LogonUser. Both pass a plain-text password that can be see by anyone hooked into the process.

Comment: @Anders Is it possible to pass the argument for LogonUser as a pointer in Memory like the documentation indicates? I want to prevent the password from being tapped with an api monitoring tool

Comment: No, only a string. Only a Kerberos type ticket coming from the network would be fully secure.

Comment: @Anders do you know a secure way to execute exe files from a user context with administration privileges where the password can not being tapped? Besides the  suggested Kerberos solution over network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Creating a regular HANDLE and passing it by reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Please press Enter to continue... " << std::endl;
    getch();

    DWORD dwLogonType = LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK;
    DWORD dwLogonProvider = LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40;
    HANDLE hToken;    

    BOOL result = LogonUserW(
        L"USERNAME",
        L"DOMAIN",
        L"PASSWORD",
        dwLogonType,
        dwLogonProvider,
        &hToken);

    if (result)
        std::cout << "It worked" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Not worked" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```